# ParserError: Expected '(' but got identifier --> dao.sol:98:10: | 98 | function correctMap(uint256 _mapId) external { |

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, blockchain, chainlink

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract EvacDAO {
    struct EvacuationMap {
        address submitter;
        string mapData;
        bool isValid;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => EvacuationMap) public maps;
    mapping(address => uint256) public stakes;
    mapping(address => bool) public hasSubmitted;

    uint256 public mapCount;
    uint256 public votingPeriod;
    uint256 public feePercentage;
    uint256 public slashingPercentage;

    constructor(uint256 _votingPeriod, uint256 _feePercentage, uint256 _slashingPercentage) {
        votingPeriod = _votingPeriod;
        feePercentage = _feePercentage;
        slashingPercentage = _slashingPercentage;
    }

    function submitMap(string memory _mapData) external {
        require(!hasSubmitted[msg.sender], "You have already submitted a map.");
        
        uint256 currentMapCount = mapCount;
        maps[currentMapCount] = EvacuationMap(msg.sender, _mapData, false);
        hasSubmitted[msg.sender] = true;
        mapCount++;

        // Stake funds
        stakes[msg.sender] += 1 ether;
    }

    function validateMap(uint256 _mapId, bool _isValid) external {
        require(msg.sender != maps[_mapId].submitter, "Cannot validate your own map.");

        // Update map validity
        maps[_mapId].isValid = _isValid;

        // Pay rewards to validator
        if (_isValid) {
            uint256 fee = (feePercentage * 1 ether) / 100;
            uint256 reward = fee * (stakes[msg.sender] / totalStakes());
            payable(msg.sender).transfer(reward);
        } else {
            // Slash funds for submitting an invalid map
            uint256 slashingFee = (slashingPercentage * 1 ether) / 100;
            uint256 slashAmount = slashingFee * stakes[msg.sender];
            stakes[msg.sender] -= slashAmount;
        }
    }

    function totalStakes() internal view returns (uint256) {
        uint256 total = 0;
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < mapCount; i++) {
            total += stakes[maps[i].submitter];
        }
        return total;
    }

    function executeVoting(uint256 _mapId) external {
        require(!maps[_mapId].isValid, "Map is already approved.");
        require(block.timestamp >= votingPeriod, "Voting period has not ended.");

        uint256 approvalVotes;
        uint256 rejectionVotes;

        // Count votes
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < mapCount; i++) {
            if (i != _mapId) {
                if (maps[i].isValid) {
                    approvalVotes += stakes[maps[i].submitter];
                } else {
                    rejectionVotes += stakes[maps[i].submitter];
                }
            }
        }

        // Determine consensus
if (approvalVotes > rejectionVotes) {
    maps[_mapId].isValid = true;

    // Pay rewards to submitter
    uint256 fee = (feePercentage * 1 ether) / 100;
    uint256 reward = fee * (stakes[maps[_mapId].submitter] / totalStakes());
    payable(maps[_mapId].submitter).transfer(reward);
} else {
    // Slash funds for submitting an invalid map
    uint256 slashingFee = (slashingPercentage * 1 ether) / 100;
    uint256 slashAmount = slashingFee * stakes[maps[_mapId].submitter];
    stakes[maps[_mapId].submitter] -= slashAmount;
}

// Correcting and validating map fees to DAO members
function correctMap(uint256 _mapId) external {
    require(maps[_mapId].isValid, "Map is not approved.");

    // Pay fees to corrector
    uint256 fee = (feePercentage * 1 ether) / 100;
    uint256 reward = (fee * stakes[msg.sender]) / totalStakes();
    payable(msg.sender).transfer(reward);
}

// Slashing fee for not reporting valid maps/invalid maps correctly
function reportInvalidMap(uint256 _mapId) external {
    require(maps[_mapId].isValid, "Map is not approved.");

    // Slash funds for not reporting correctly
    uint256 slashingFee = (slashingPercentage * 1 ether) / 100;
    uint256 slashAmount = (slashingFee * stakes[msg.sender]) / totalStakes();
    stakes[msg.sender] -= slashAmount;
}
```

Comment: There isn't any error in this code. I copy pasted it and this seems okay.

Comment: ParserError: Expected '(' but got identifier
  --> dao.sol:98:10:
   |
98 | function correctMap(uint256 _mapId) external {
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^

both in remix and truffle i got this error

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
    
    contract EvacDAO {
        struct EvacuationMap {
            address submitter;
            string mapData;
            bool isValid;
        }
    
        mapping(uint256 => EvacuationMap) public maps;
        mapping(address => uint256) public stakes;
        mapping(address => bool) public hasSubmitted;
    
        uint256 public mapCount;
        uint256 public votingPeriod;
        uint256 public feePercentage;
        uint256 public slashingPercentage;
    
        constructor(uint256 _votingPeriod, uint256 _feePercentage, uint256 _slashingPercentage) {
            votingPeriod = _votingPeriod;
            feePercentage = _feePercentage;
            slashingPercentage = _slashingPercentage;
        }
    
        function submitMap(string memory _mapData) external {
            require(!hasSubmitted[msg.sender], "You have already submitted a map.");
    
            uint256 currentMapCount = mapCount;
            maps[currentMapCount] = EvacuationMap(msg.sender, _mapData, false);
            hasSubmitted[msg.sender] = true;
            mapCount++;
    
            // Stake funds
            stakes[msg.sender] += 1 ether;
        }
    
        function validateMap(uint256 _mapId, bool _isValid) external {
            require(msg.sender != maps[_mapId].submitter, "Cannot validate your own map.");
    
            // Update map validity
            maps[_mapId].isValid = _isValid;
    
            // Pay rewards to validator
            if (_isValid) {
                uint256 fee = (feePercentage * 1 ether) / 100;
                uint256 reward = (fee * stakes[msg.sender]) / totalStakes();
                payable(msg.sender).transfer(reward);
            } else {
                // Slash funds for submitting an invalid map
                uint256 slashingFee = (slashingPercentage * 1 ether) / 100;
                uint256 slashAmount = (slashingFee * stakes[msg.sender]) / totalStakes();
                stakes[msg.sender] -= slashAmount;
            }
        }
    
        function totalStakes() internal view returns (uint256) {
            uint256 total = 0;
            for (uint256 i = 0; i < mapCount; i++) {
                total += stakes[maps[i].submitter];
            }
            return total;
        }
    
        function executeVoting(uint256 _mapId) external {
            require(!maps[_mapId].isValid, "Map is already approved.");
            require(block.timestamp >= votingPeriod, "Voting period has not ended.");
    
            uint256 approvalVotes;
            uint256 rejectionVotes;
    
            // Count votes
            for (uint256 i = 0; i < mapCount; i++) {
                if (i != _mapId) {
                    if (maps[i].isValid) {
                        approvalVotes += stakes[maps[i].submitter];
                    } else {
                        rejectionVotes += stakes[maps[i].submitter];
                    }
                }
            }
    
            // Determine consensus
            if (approvalVotes > rejectionVotes) {
                maps[_mapId].isValid = true;
    
                // Pay rewards to submitter
                uint256 fee = (feePercentage * 1 ether) / 100;
                uint256 reward = (fee * stakes[maps[_mapId].submitter]) / totalStakes();
                payable(maps[_mapId].submitter).transfer(reward);
            } else {
                // Slash funds for submitting an invalid map
                uint256 slashingFee = (slashingPercentage * 1 ether) / 100;
                uint256 slashAmount = (slashingFee * stakes[maps[_mapId].submitter]) / totalStakes();
                stakes[maps[_mapId].submitter] -= slashAmount;
            }
    
        }
        // Correcting and validating map fees to DAO members
        function correctMap(uint256 _mapId) external {
            require(maps[_mapId].isValid, "Map is not approved.");
    
            // Pay fees to corrector
            uint256 fee = (feePercentage * 1 ether) / 100;
            uint256 reward = (fee * stakes[msg.sender]) / totalStakes();
            payable(msg.sender).transfer(reward);
        }
    
        // Slashing fee for not reporting valid maps/invalid maps correctly
        function reportInvalidMap(uint256 _mapId) external {
            require(maps[_mapId].isValid, "Map is not approved.");
    
            // Slash funds for not reporting correctly
            uint256 slashingFee = (slashingPercentage * 1 ether) / 100;
            uint256 slashAmount = (slashingFee * stakes[msg.sender]) / totalStakes();
            stakes[msg.sender] -= slashAmount;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please do explain the changes as well.

Comment: thank you, of course it was the // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT .. -.-.-